# Running a pass-through query without being prompted for server credentials each time

Tags: ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I have a pass-through query in Access that uses data from Oracle. Whenever I run the query it will give me the dialog box to enter my Oracle credentials.

Is there any ways to auto fill the ODBC log on popups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new pass-through query, and after you have entered your login credentials see if you receive a prompt asking you if you want to save them in the connection string:

[image: SavePassword.png]

If you don't receive that prompt then saved passwords may have been disabled by your administrators and you'll probably just have to enter the credentials each time.

If you do receive that prompt then try re-creating the extsting pass-through query and saving the password when prompted.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you can save the password , only if you put the connecting string in the related parameter in properties. If you don't do it , you have to insert every time the password.

If you clic in the the query properties button, as shown in the screenshot, then you should get the prompt asking you if you want to save password.

[image]